# Создание Flash плеера

Tags: flash

Здравствуйте. Хотелось бы узнать, как можно создать видео-аудио проигрыватель по примеру YouTube, RuTube, плеер на ВКонтакте. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

[Flow Player](http://flowplayer.org/):

> Setup video for your site in minutes.

[Open Source Media Framework](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/video_osmf.html):

> Building progressive video players in Flash

Answer (score 2):

Начинаем дружить с ActionScript 3.0 , Adobe Flash CS5, помню сам когда то возился с этим плеером, нормальных документаций не находил, разбирался сам. Вот код :

```
//Подружаем нужные библиотеки
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.Float;
//Функции загрузки
var requester : URLRequest      =   new URLRequest('http://webcast.emg.fm:55655/europaplus128.mp3');// Адрес музыкального файла
var loader : URLLoader          =   new URLLoader();//Переменная - загрузчик того, что пришло в ответ
loader.load(requester);//Сам процесс загрузки
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);//Добавили событие, которое вызовет функцию продолжения по окончанию загрузки
//Функции воспроизведения
function loaded(event:Event):void{//Вызовется как только загрузка будет завершена
    var soundFactory : Sound    =   new Sound();//Создадим объект типа Sound
    soundFactory.load(requester);//Загрузим в объект Sound подгуженый муз. файл
    soundFactory.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, playSound);//По окнчанию загрузки начать воспроизведение
    function playSound(event:Event):void{//Функция вызов воспроизведения
        var channel1 : SoundChannel =   soundFactory.play();//Создадим объект типа Channel и присвоим ему воспроизведение загруженного файла
    }
}
```

Это минимальный код для проигрывания mp3 файла, очень надеюсь, что помог.

Answer (score 1):

Советую вам почитать [статью](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/28196/) на хабре, а так же вот пример отличного [плеера](http://sublimevideo.net/) на HTML5, правда не знаю что там с исходниками.

---

Но можно и самому, зная Action Script и Flash сделать плеер, но автор задал вопрос, а значит требуемых навыков не имеет, следовательно следуйте по ссылкам и собирайте плеер на вкус :)